# How can I smooth an edge from a cut-out?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I have a rounded "onion looking" shape and have used a Boolean modifier to cut a hole out of it:

[image]

Now I'm trying to smooth out the edges so there are no harsh corners on the shape. How can I do this?

Here I have highlighted the area I'm trying to smooth out:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Once you've applied the boolean, rearrange the topology so that it's a good one, then bevel the edge:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you explain what you did between image 3 and 4? It looks like the bevel becomes larger, trying to learn that step. Thank you

Comment: I think I just moved along the edges (select an edge loop, press GG and move along Y) and scaled it?

Answer (score 1):

First in first, the faces cut out by boolean modifier will use the data from that cutting cylinder. So you need to set that cylinder smooth in shading.

> [image]
>   Note: I am using bounding box to display that cylinder

Due to how boolean work, you might want to apply sub-modifier before boolean modifier and make all your object smooth.

[image]

And also, vertices cannot be smooth by sub-modifier after boolean modifier (the crease value seems to be dropped), so you will need to add sub-modifier on that cylinder too.

> You can download this example here:
>   [image]
>
> ---